# Copy directory before update and import after compile.

Tags: heroku, docker

I have an assets folder in the environment where pictures are uploaded, is there a way to copy this folder and import it after the image has compiled?

Or can I somehow use a folder outside of the image instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what Docker volumes are for: http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/

Be sure to have a look at other concepts in the documentation as well. There is some great stuff there ;)